# $OABCD$ tetrahedron with $OA ⊥ OB ⊥ OC ⊥ OA$

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, polyhedra

I've got stuck at this problem:

> Let $OABCD$ be a tetrahedron 
>   with $OA ⊥ OB ⊥ OC ⊥ OA$. If $OH$ is the orthocentre of triangle $ABC$, show that $OH$ is 
>   perpendicular on plan $(ABC)$.
>   Then prove that $OA^2 + OB^2 + OC^2 = 9OH^2$.

Since I'm not familiar to any of these programs where you can make geometry drawings, I'm just showing my pencil drawing below (please let me know if the drawing is unclear):
[image]

The first thing that came to my mind was *Theorem of Three Perpendiculars*, but I wasn't able to solve it.

I would really apreciate some hints.

Thanks!

Comment: Denote $H'$ the orthogonal projection of $O$ onto the plane $ABC$, and show that $AH'\perp BC$ via Theorem of Three Perps, then deduce that $H'=H$.

Comment: This is one case where a coordinatized approach might be reasonable - consider a frame where (the suggestively-named) $O$ is the origin and $OA$, $OB$, $OC$ are the three axes.